# Unable to retrieve data when I use the data access layer technique dataset & adapters

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008

I maybe approaching this the wrong way. I'm unable to retrieve data when I use the data access layer technique. If I use the following code in the main class it works:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     myCon.connectionString();
     string SomeString = string.Empty;

     SomeString = "SELECT * FROM TableA";
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SomeString, myCon.Con);
     adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     ds = new DataSet();
     adapter.Fill(ds, "TableA");

     txtID.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][0].ToString();
     txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][1].ToString();
     txtLastName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][2].ToString();
}
```

If I place the above code in another class I am unable to retrieve data and there are no errors.

ClassA:

```
public void Button(string id, string firstname, string lastname)
{
     myCon.connectionString();
     string SomeString = string.Empty;

     SqlConnection cnn = myCon.Con;

     cnn.Open();          

     CmdString = "SELECT * FROM TableA";
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, cnn.Con);
     adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     ds = new DataSet();
     adapter.Fill(ds, "Table");

     id = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][0].ToString();
     firstname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][1].ToString();
     lastname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][2].ToString();
}
```

Main class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
     ClassA objs = new ClassA();

     private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         objs.Button(txtID.Text, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text);
     }
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me here.

Comment: You are passing copies of strings as the parameters, not the strings themselves. I'd also suggest using bindings instead of explicit value assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set the values of `txtID.Text`, `txtFirstName.Text`, etc., through your call to `objs.Button`?

That's an interesting approach, but it won't work as written because of the way the parameters are being passed.  When you change the value of a string variable, you aren't changing the variable itself but assigning a whole new string to it.  So when you reassign your parameters in your routine, you are no longer pointing to the `.Text` property of your controls, but to different strings.  The `.Text` property remains unchanged.

There are several ways around this, but the simplest might be to change the signature of your subroutine:

```
   public void Button(TextBox textId, TextBox txtFirstname, TextBox txtLastname)
    {

      myCon.connectionString();
      string SomeString = string.Empty;

      SqlConnection cnn = myCon.Con;


      cnn.Open();
      {

        CmdString = "SELECT * FROM TableA";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, cnn.Con);
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Table");

        txtId.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][0].ToString();
        txtFirstname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][1].ToString();
        txtLastname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][2].ToString();
      }

 }
```

Other options would be to have a series of `out` parameters after your input parameters.  You might also be able to make it work with the `ref` keyword, but I'm not sure of that.